# SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: fget

Tags: python

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self,height,width) :
        self.Height = height
        self.Width = width

    def _get_Height(self):
        return self.Height
    
    def _set_Height(self,value):
        self.Height = value
    
    def _get_Width(self):
        return self.Width
    
    def _set_Width(self,value2):
        self.Width = value2

    
    Dimensions = property(fget = _get_Height, fset = _set_Height, fget = _get_Width, fset = _set_Width)
```

I was getting an error inside the property parenthesis:

```
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: fget
```

Highlighted underneath [ fget = _get_Width ]

Comment: You can only create one property at a time. In general you can't pass the same keyword twice anywhere - if you called `foo(bar=123, bar=456)` how would that work, what would the value of the `bar` parameter be inside the function? But why not use the decorator (or, given that your properties are pointless, just use regular attributes)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set the `fget=` and `fset=` parameters twice each in the `property` function, which is not allowed to happen (in any function, ever). What you probably want to do is create functions which: return a tuple (getter), and accept a tuple (setter), either using lambdas or normal functions.

Also, the `_get_width`, `_get_height`, `_set_width`, and `_set_height` functions are pointless, as you can use them as normal attributes. Instead just use one function for getting (`_get_dims`) and one for setting (`_set_dims`).

In this way, you can also use the `property` [decorator](https://pythonbasics.org/decorators/) to create a property, instead of just using it as a normal function, which makes the code clearer.

The full code would be:

```py
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, width, height) :
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    @property
    def dimensions(self):
        return (self.width, self.height)
    
    @dimensions.setter
    def dimensions(self, new_dims):
        self.width = new_dims[0]
        self.height = new_dims[1]
```

*Also note that variable names of things other than classes should always be lower case in Python, so I have changed the variable names accordingly.*

*Also, it is more normal to take width first and then height, so I have changed the order in the constructor to `width, height`, not `height, width`, but you can change this back if necessary.*

Comment: Thank you. Still trying to understand property.